# identify many cell in uitable view

Tags: ios, swift, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview

I want to identify many custom cell in table view  "i build them in storyboard " but the are error ask from me to return value , i am trying to return nil and int value and cell but the error be same

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CheefsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        return cell }
    else if indexPath == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BeautyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
            return cell }
    else if indexPath == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StudentServicesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        return cell }
    else if indexPath == 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArtAndDesigneCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        return cell }
    else if indexPath == 4 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StoreCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        return cell }
    else if indexPath == 5 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OthersCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        return cell }
    return

}
```

update :: 
[git hub link /](https://github.com/BusinessWallet/BW1.git)

Comment: `if indexPath == 1` etc. does not make sense should be `if indexPath.row == 1` etc.

Comment: As @beyowulf noted, indexPath is a path to a nested array of collections. It cannot be compared to an integer.

Comment: do you have a different cell subclass for each row of your table?

Comment: i have 6 different cell in my table view

Answer (score 1):

The method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` requires to return a non-optional `UITableViewCell`, so you must ensure to return a cell in any case. A simple `return` or `return nil` is not allowed.

The code can be simplified, most of it is redundant. The only difference is the identifier.

A suitable solution is a switch statement on the `row` property of the indexpath.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {

  var identifier : String
  switch indexPath.row {
  case 0: identifier = "CheefsCell"
  case 1: identifier = "BeautyCell"
  case 2: identifier = "StudentServicesCell"
  case 3: identifier = "ArtAndDesigneCell"
  case 4: identifier = "StoreCell"
  default:  identifier = "OthersCell"
  }
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
  cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
  return cell
}
```

Comment: You could also use an array, no?

Comment: still there are error "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CheefsCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard" i will update question to share git hob link

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error cause you're not returning a cell from the method.

1. Change your code so it **always** returns a cell.
2. When checking `indexPaths`, use their row property - `indexPath.row`.
3. Consider replacing your `if-else` tree with `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Another example based on @vadian's answer:

```
static let identifiers = [ "CheefsCell", "BeautyCell", "StudentServicesCell", "ArtAndDesigneCell", "StoreCell" ]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {

    let identifier = (indexPath.row < count) ? identifiers[ indexPath.row ] : "OthersCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell() // allocate a new cell here
    }

    cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    // configure your cell here

    return cell
}
```

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returns never `nil`

Comment: why? did you register your cell types?

Comment: Because the method is declared to return a non-optional type. Using this method the cells are designed in Interface Builder